Suppressing Content Approval Status Change After Signature
I am new to SharePoint and Power Automate, and I don't even know if either of these are able to solve this problem. I have a SharePoint library functioning as a document routing system. The current library settings require content approval for submitted items and have versioning turned on.
When a document (mostly PDFs) are ready for my approval and signature it is submitted and the status is changed from 'Draft' to 'Pending'. For most of the files I then have to download them, digitally sign them in Adobe, and reupload them to the library, with the same file name (so I select to replace the existing file in the library with the recently signed one). This then changes the status back to 'Draft' and requires me to manually submit each file before I can then approve it. Is there a way to stop the status from changing back to 'Draft' when I reupload the file?
Note: There is a Power Automate flow I created in place that sends me a message on Teams whenever a file is submitted, so before I even look at the files the 'Modified by' column already has my name.
